# Mysqli always commits, even on failure

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 4 MySQL INSERT statements going into various tables of a database, and sometimes one of them fails and the rest insert garbage data. I'm trying to convert the code to a MySQL Transaction, but it executes the same as before, there is no all or nothing transaction, all insertions are made if that particular insertion doesn't fail.

```
$insert="INSERT INTO table STUFF";

//database transaction, completes all insertions or none
try {
    //turn autocommit off and begin transaction
    mysqli_autocommit($connection, false);

    //do insert 1
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$insert);
    if (!$result) {
        throw new Exception('Error in Insert 1: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
    }

    //do insert2 3 and 4
    ...

    //commit changes upon success
    mysqli_commit($connection);
    echo "records added";

} catch (Exception $e) {

    //rollback upon failure
    mysqli_rollback($connection);
    echo "no records added";
}
```

Comment: Try this way: if ($result === false) {
        throw new Exception('Error in Insert 1: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
    }

Comment: Your auto save in mysql must have been enabled.

Comment: What is the 'auto save'??

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was trying to solve with this was that sometimes one of the inserts would fail, and I would not want the other to happen. What I ended up doing was restructuring the inserts so that they wouldn't fail. I've done a few hundred inserts in a row so far without issue.

The root of the problem was a misunderstanding of the table schema on my part.